# android deep linking doest not works correctly

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-chrome

I have the need that from a web page (in my case, I am using chrome as my default browser), a native android application that I am developing is loaded.

The flow would be the following:

In chrome a form is submitted and through javascript the application is invoked with the uri scheme:

```
window.open ("example: // yyyy");
```

This, invokes the Android application and it opens correctly and I can use it.

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="*"
                    android:scheme="example" />
            </intent-filter>
```

The problem is in chrome. After doing the window.open, it makes an ajax request that waits for the process in the application to finish. As I have seen in the chrome inspector, it does a redirect to the menu option that takes you to the page where the form was. And this does not wait.

The weird thing is that when I submit the form, if I exit chrome at that moment (before the javascript execution starts), the process is done correctly. It is waiting to finish the action in the Android application. Is it possible that the problem is that chrome stops executing the script? How could I fix it?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do (in a simple way)?

Comment: @a7d.24_
open a native android application from chrome. And at that moment, chrome is waiting for the application to finish a process that is being done. But the problem that I comment occurs

Comment: @a7d.24_ in firefox works correctly.